# C99: Equality operator expression to bool conversion warning

Tags: c, type-conversion, language-lawyer, c99

I am compiling the following code using WindRiver Diab for Power PC, a proprietary C99 compiler for embedded systems:

```
  #include <stdbool.h>
  
  bool foo(int a, int b)
  {
      return a == b; /* int to unsigned char conversion */
  }
```

I had expected this code to compile without warnings, but is no, the compiler reports:

> warning: ... signed-to-unsigned type conversion found: **int to unsigned char**

On one hand, as the the type of the equality operator expression is `int` and the type of `bool` (in this case) is apparently `unsigned char`, the warning seems to make sense. On the other hand, the code looks pretty standard. Shouldn't it compile without warnings? What is the standard saying?

Comment: Might you share what compiler is it? `without warnings` Warnings are internal stuff of a compiler, it's a quality of implementation of that specific compiler. So `Shouldn't it compile without warnings? What is the standard saying?` The standard doesn't mention any warnings and doesn't care about warnings.

Comment: @KamilCuk WindRiver Diab for Power PC

Comment: @KamilCuk I understand that, probably the question is not well phrased. I mean if there is anything specific about the equality operator expression to bool conversion, which would be applicable to this example.

Comment: When asked for details, edit them into the question; do not leave them as comments.

Comment: This would appear to be a shortcoming in the C implementation. `x == true` produces an `int` value, and the `return` from a `bool` function causes to be converted to a `bool`, which the C implementation’s `<stdbool.h>` apparently defines as `unsigned char`. The compiler is warning you that converting an `int` to an `unsigned char` can, in general, produce a value different from the original `int`. That cannot happen here, as `==` produces only 0 or 1, both of which convert to `unsigned char` without problem, but the compiler fails to take that in to account.

Comment: As for working around it, you might try `return x;`, as `== true` is redundant. Or you could try `return (bool) (x == true);`. Or you could disable that warning. You should also write a letter of complaint to the supplier.

Comment: Worth mentioning that including `<stdbool.h>`, according to the standard, should result in `bool` expanding to `_Bool` rather than `unsigned char`, so it would seem that the compiler does not conform to the C99 standard.

Comment: Unless, possibly, somewhere in the program itself they are redefining these macros.

Comment: Note that even if bool is represented as an unsigned char, conversion from int to bool is _not_ the same as conversion from int to unsigned char. It's defined by the C99 standard as converting anything that compares equal to 0 as false, and everything else to true.

Comment: Some [product information](https://www.windriver.com/themes/Windriver/pdf/PN_Compiler_0110.pdf) does say it supports C99. Are you sure you are using it in C99 mode? What does `printf("%d\n", (bool) 256);` print?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, I am using it in C99 mode. I can't `printf` easily, as it is an embedded device. But in the assembly file I can see that a `1` is passed as a second argument to `printf`.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons It's not *necessarily* non-conforming. The only possible non-conformance I see is an incorrect warning message, and that's not covered by the standard. But yes, it's certainly a strong clue that the compiler is treating `bool` as the same type as `unsigned char`, which would be non-conforming. (And any `... == true` comparison is suspect.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil *You should also write a letter of complaint to the supplier.*  Which supplier?  The supplier of the compiler?  Or the supplier of the `bool is_true(bool x)` code?  The answer to "How do a check if `bool x;` is true?" is not "With a function! `if (is_true( x ))`!", it's `if (x)`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Why not both?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Please note, this is just a minimal example, to reproduce the warning. Obviously, that is not production code. (The actual code is checking bit patterns.)

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Please note, this is just a minimal example, to reproduce the warning. Obviously, that is not production code. The actual code is checking bit patterns.

Comment: @sergej I've seen much worse production code than that.  Much worse.  Some of it written by some one who put my name in the change log...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A warning is proper, but pedantic. The result of `==` is certainly `int` (C 1999, §6.5.9 ¶3). And `_Bool` (what `bool` expands into) is one of the *standard unsigned integer types* (C 1999, §6.2.5 ¶6). Of course, `bool` expands to `_Bool` (C 1999, §7.16 ¶2).

However, since the result of `==` is either 0 or 1, the compiler could deduce it will not suffer any ill effects from the conversion, and the warning could have been suppressed. In particular, conversion to `_Bool` is well defined to be either 0 or 1 (C 1999, §6.3.1.2 ¶1).

The warning shown in the question does not mention conversion to `bool` or `_Bool`, but instead mentions `unsigned char`. This seems out of place, and is another indication that the quality of the compiler could be improved.<sup>†</sup>

For comparison, GCC requires `-Wconversion` be added specifically to get these conversion warnings. Even with the flag, GCC does not generate any warning when converting result of `==` to `unsigned`. And, it does not generate any warning for any arithmetic conversion (including negative values) to `_Bool`.

---

†<sub>Keith Thompson notes in a comment that `_Bool` and `unsigned char` are distinct types in C and cannot be treated as compatible types.</sub>

Comment: If the warning had said "signed-to-unsigned type conversion found: int to bool" or "int to _Bool", I'd call it proper but pedantic. But there is no conversion to `unsigned char`, so the warning is at best incorrect. (The standard doesn't require warnings to be correct, so this doesn't necessarily imply any failure to conform.)

Comment: @KeithThompson I agree that it is not a very helpful message, and also speaks to quality of implementation. Perhaps internally the compiler used `unsigned char` to represent `_Bool`.

Comment: Perhaps. But if it does so in a way that makes `_Bool` and `unsigned char` compatible, it's non-conforming. For example this: `_Bool *pb = 0;
unsigned char *puc = pb;` requires a diagnostic.